# C2228 - Vector methods do not work when vector is named in certain way

Tags: c++

I have this weird problem all of a sudden. In the header, I've put two members like this:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Component>> m_test1;
std::vector<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Component>>> m_test2;
std::vector<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Component>>> m_componentsByType;
std::vector<std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Component>>> m_componentsByTypes;
```

Now, when I try to call method on these vectors, a weird thing happens:

```
m_test1.pop_back(); // OK
m_test2.pop_back(); // OK
m_componentsByType.pop_back(); // C2228
m_componentsByTypes.pop_back(); // OK
```

The error C2228 expands to:

```
error C2228: left of '.pop_back' must have class/struct/union
```

What could cause that `m_componentsByType` is the only one that doesn't work? Could this have something to do with VS2013? I've tried cleaning the project, but it doesn't seem to help. If I change a single character in the variable name and all the references, the code compiles and runs perfectly, but with that specific variable name, every reference causes a compiler error.

Forgot to mention that originally I had the exact same variable name, but with a different type. I changed the type and the error appeared.

Comment: `1` Not everybody uses VS. Can you elaborate on what C2228 is? `2` Check if you perhaps have a macro named `m_componentsByType` defined somewhere.

Comment: Could you post the full error message here please? Not everyone will actually remember what `C2228` actually says.

Comment: Are you sure you are not misspelling the name?

Comment: Is there a `m_componentsByType` anywhere else in your source files or headers ?

Comment: @ChronoTrigger Yes, absolutely sure. I copy-pasted it straight from the header.

Comment: @PaulR Nope, and there's no macros at all in the project.

Comment: Code compiles just fine. Either `m_componentsByType` is misspelled or it's shadowed by another variable.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Not misspelled (keyboard shortcut takes from reference to the declaration). I tried adding another variable with the same name in different portion, and this caused a redefinition error. If there's already another variable with the same name, shouldn't it raise a redefinition error as well?

Comment: @manabreak _"shouldn't it raise a redefinition error as well?"_ - only if they are defined at the same scope.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious Even so, I searched the whole project and there's no other variable with that name.

Comment: Generate preprocessor listing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6.aspx) and read resulting file. This can give additional information.

Comment: [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @AlexFarber The result seems to be almost 100k lines. I searched for the variable name, but didn't find anything suspicious.

Comment: Look for `m_test2` and `m_componentsByType` in this file. What do you see after first `m_test2` inclusion? How `m_componentsByType` is declared and used?

Comment: @AlexFarber Ooh, found it! It seems that somehow a single method's name was changed to `m_componentsByType()` - quite probably due to a misclick or a mishap with keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: Well, I posted this an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `/P` (Preprocess to a File) preprocessor switch allows to generate text file, which contains the code handled by compiler. Reading this file (mostly searching in it, because this is huge file) allows to solve such kind of problems. For example, search for `m_componentsByType` in preprocessed file may give an idea, why compiler is not happy.

For reference: `/P (Preprocess to a File)` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6.aspx

In addition, IDE functions like "Go to definition" and "Find all references", and the same functions in Visual Assist (if used) can help.